# Issue with basic server/client code

Tags: c++, sockets, networking

I'm attempting to teach myself some networking programming in C++, but I'm running into some core issues that I can't seem to solve.

I have two programs that are in the same VS project- a client and a server. They don't exchange information, they simply connect and tell me when the connection is established. Here is the client file-

**SERVER.CPP**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    //setting up WSA
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int WSAcheck = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    //checking WSA
    if (WSAcheck != 0)
    {
        printf("WSA couldn't start correctly\n");
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //setting up the socket
    SOCKET serversock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //checking socket's validity
    if (serversock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket isn't valid: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //setting up the sockaddr_in for bind()
    sockaddr_in server_sockaddr;
    server_sockaddr.sin_family = AF_INET;
    server_sockaddr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    server_sockaddr.sin_port = htons(25565);

    //binding the socket.
    int bindcheck = bind(serversock, (struct sockaddr *)&server_sockaddr, sizeof(server_sockaddr));

    //checking to see if the bind worked, and calling the error if it doesn't
    if (bindcheck != 0)
    {
        printf("Bind failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //setting the socket to listen
    int listencheck = listen(serversock, 10);

    //checking to make sure the listen command was successful
    if (listencheck != 0)
    {
        printf("Listen failed: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //telling that the socket is being set to listen
    printf("Socket is ready to accept connections\n");

    //accepting any incoming connections
    SOCKET clientsocket = accept(serversock, NULL, NULL);

    //checking the socket
    if (clientsocket == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Connecting socket isn't valid or has timed out: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        exit;
    }
    //ending the program
    printf("fin\n");
    pause();
}
```

**CLIENT.CPP**

```
#include "stdafx.h"

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    //setting up WSA
    WSADATA wsaData;
    int WSAcheck = WSAStartup(MAKEWORD(2, 2), &wsaData);

    //checking WSA
    if (WSAcheck != 0)
    {
        printf("WSA couldn't start correctly\n");
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //setting up the socket
    SOCKET clientsock = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    //checking socket's validity
    if (clientsock == INVALID_SOCKET)
    {
        printf("Socket isn't valid: %d\n", WSAGetLastError());
        pause();
        exit;
    }

    //setting up the struct with the connection info
    sockaddr_in serverinfo;
    serverinfo.sin_family = AF_INET;
    serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
    serverinfo.sin_port = htons(25565);

    //connecting
    printf("Trying to connect\n");
    connect(clientsock, (SOCKADDR *)&serverinfo, sizeof(serverinfo));
    printf("Passed the connect function\n");
    pause();
}
```

**STDAFX.H**

```
// stdafx.h : include file for standard system include files,
// or project specific include files that are used frequently, but
// are changed infrequently

#pragma once

#include "targetver.h"

#include <stdio.h>
#include <tchar.h>
#include <winsock2.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <Inaddr.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <Windef.h>
#include <Ws2tcpip.h>
#include <WinNT.h>
#include <Windows.h>
#include <tchar.h>

void pause(void);  //defined in stdafx.cpp
```

pause is defined as getchar(), to break the code to see what is going on.

The output for the client is -

*Trying to connect

Passed the connect function*

regardless of whether the server process is running.

The output for the server is

*The socket is ready to accept connections*

regardless of what I test, I cannot get it to pass that.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you check the return value for the `connect` call and add the results?

Answer (score 3):

You have an error in the client. This is bad:

```
serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY;
```

Instead of INADDR_ANY you have to write the server IP address, maybe 127.0.0.1 if they run in the same server, in binary format.
Use this function to convert from text IP address to binary IP address:

```
INT WSAAPI InetPton(
  _In_   INT  Family,
  _In_   PCTSTR pszAddrString,
  _Out_  PVOID pAddrBuf
);
```

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/cc805844(v=vs.85).aspx

The code would be:

```
if(InetPton(AF_INET, "192.168.0.1", (void*)&serverinfo.sin_addr.s_addr) <= 0)
{
    //error
}
```

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. Does INADDR_ANY work with the server in the sense that a connection attempt on any local interface to port XXXX will be received by the process, or does INADDR_ANY mean just 0.0.0.0?


EDIT: Ah, I remember this function now- I had a real struggle with this a few weeks ago trying to get the data types in the right form. Thanks for the example!

Comment: @ThomasWoods, your comment's first 2 lines are correct!

Comment: I'm having issues with your second section of code with the InetPton function- The docs say that the second parameter needs to be a pointer to a const TSTR. I've defined unicode, so I'm using the follow code to but the binary address into the buffer specified by the third parameter in InetPton()-

[I put it on pastebin for formatting](http://pastebin.com/w0UPZ6D6)